# Change y-axis value of PlotItem pyqtgraph

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqtgraph

I want to change the value of the y-axis of PlotItem, Let's say i have 1-10 y plot values, what i want is change the display values of y-axis to 100 - 1000.

```
graph = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(QWidget)
graph.addLabel(text="label", justify='center', col=0, row=5, colspan=4)
plot_widget = graph.addPlot(row=8, col=0, colspan=2)
plot_widget.setLabel("left", "time" , units="s")
plot_widget.setYRange(0, 100)
plot_widget.setLimits(xMin=0, xMax=100, yMin=0, yMax=100)
```

How can i change the display values?